# Searching/filtering two concatenated columns in cgridview

Tags: yii

cgridview code in admi.php

```
array(
    'header'=>'Client Name',
        'name'=>'client_name',
        'value'=>'$data->first_name." ".$data->last_name', //or u can write also value'=>'$data->first_name.\' \'.$data->last_name', 
    ),
```

model search() class in client.php

```
 public $client_name;

$criteria->compare('CONCAT(first_name,last_name)',$this->client_name,true);
```

Concatenation **and displaying** is done but seraching the data show no results found?

Comment: i m not yelling just show problem issue?

Comment: A question title all in caps/uppercase is considered yelling.

Comment: @Filburt,thanks for your information.

Comment: @MuhammadHamdani, Filburt is talking about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59757/what-is-meant-by-acceptance-rate as well.  Generally if you don't accept answers, after a while, people will stop answering your questions because you don't accept them (and they therefore don't get any reputation points).

Comment: @Filburt how to accept the answers??? so that others may get reputation points.thanks

Comment: @MuhammadHamdani If you do not like the concept that people are rewarded with reputation points for providing helpful answers maybe this site isn't for you.

Comment: @Filburt this is not the answer of my question.d'nt hurt anyone if you d'nt know.

Comment: @Filburt . ithink yiiframeowk.com is the best site in the world for good and ethical users.

Answer (score 3):

**In model** :

```
   class User extends CActiveRecord
    {
            public $fullName;
}
```

**in search**

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('concat(first_name, " ", last_name)', $this->fullName);
```

**in rules()**

```
array('..., fullName', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
```

**in model**  created a function

```
public function getFullName()
        {
                return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
        }
```

And last  put it in your **view**:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

        .......
          'columns' => array(
                array(
                        'name' => 'full_name',
                        'value' => '$data->getFullName()',
                ),

                ...
```