# Is it possible to use IN conditions in yii compare

Tags: php, yii

Hi I am trying to create a search functionality with yii `CDbCriteria` every thing is ok . But when i enter the full name .i.e `manoj dhiman` I have saved this as `firstname` and `lastname` in the db . So i explode the searched key and so i need something like so that i can search the result with compere of that array . My code is

```
public function actionSearchuser()
    {
        $key=$_POST['key'];
        $data=array();
        if($key)
        {
            $users=explode(' ',$key);   // the users array 
            $model=new Goals;
            $model->attributes = $_POST['key'];
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->with='profile';
            $criteria->distinct=true;

            //$criteria->addInCondition('firstname',$users);
            $criteria->compare('firstname', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('school', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('occupation', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('location', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('lastname', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('username', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('email', $key, true, 'OR');


             $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
                'criteria' => $criteria
        ));

            $data=$dataProvider->getData();
        }
        $this->renderPartial('Searchuser',array('data'=>$data));
    }
```

I also tried the `$criteria->addInCondition('firstname',$users);` but is is matching the whole key with name . I want `like`. How it is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: may be related: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/610/how-to-create-a-criteria-condition-for-a-multiple-value-text-search-i-e-a-like-in/

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449410/searching-filtering-two-concatenated-columns-in-cgridview

Comment: @InsaneSkulll thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after insane skull's comment it works for me . `$criteria->compare('concat(firstname, " ", lastname)', $key, true, 'OR');`  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449410/searching-filtering-two-concatenated-columns-in-cgridview)

```
public function actionSearchuser()
    {
        $key=$_POST['key'];
        $data=array();
        if($key)
        {
            $users=explode(' ',$key);
            $model=new Goals;
            $model->attributes = $_POST['key'];
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->with='profile';
            $criteria->distinct=true;

            //$criteria->addInCondition('firstname',$users);
            $criteria->compare('firstname', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('concat(firstname, " ", lastname)', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('school', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('occupation', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('location', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('lastname', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('username', $key, true, 'OR');
            $criteria->compare('email', $key, true, 'OR');


             $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
                'criteria' => $criteria
        ));

            $data=$dataProvider->getData();
        }
        $this->renderPartial('Searchuser',array('data'=>$data));
    }
```